# MaterialDesign elements does not dispay checkbox in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, material-design

I have a `ListView` and there is some elements inside of its. The displaying of all elements is okay except `CheckBox`. I don't know how to deal with. There is `CheckBox` content but does not display itself because of unknown issue.

[image]

Here's the code :

```
  <ListView BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="10 10 0 0"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Products,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="auto"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Taxable" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <CheckBox  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignLightCheckBox}" Content="{Binding Taxable}" IsChecked="{Binding Taxable}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Barcode" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding Barcode}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Category" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding Category}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding QuantityType.Title}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding Quantity}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Margin" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding MarginPrice}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="95">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Padding="5.0" Text="{Binding Price}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>
```

Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: Looks like a problem in the Style resource MaterialDesignLightCheckBox...

Comment: does it work without setting Content on the Checkbox? Makes no sense showing "True" "False" anyway.

Comment: When you bind content of a checkbox you're setting the text next to the box. You should not be doing that at all. ( As I think Blechdose is saying). Remove Content="{Binding Taxable}" It's possible the box part won't fit as well as the word.